# Array of Objects with NullPointerException

Tags: jsp

I am writing a JSP program with a java class and trying to build an array of objects, but getting NullPointerException. Kindly sort out my problem.

My java class is `MChart.java` is here below:

```
package myPackages;

public class MChart 
{
    private  String[] stateId = new String [100];  
    private  String[] rule      = new String[100];
    private  String[] dotPosition   = new String[100];
    private  String[] backPointer   = new String [100];
    private  String[] operation = new String[100];

    public void intialize (String s, String r, String dp, String bp, String o)
    {

        stateId[0]  =   s;
        rule[0]     =   r;
        dotPosition[0]  =   dp;
        backPointer[0]  =   bp;
        operation[0]    =   o;

    }
    public String getStateID(int i)
    {
        return stateId[i];
    }
    public String getRule(int i)
    {
        return rule[i];
    }
    public String getDotPosition(int i)
    {
        return dotPosition[i];
    }
    public String getBackPointer(int i)
    {
        return backPointer[i];
    }
    public String getOperation(int i)
    {
        return operation[i];
    }
}
```

and now my jsp file is as below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="myPackages.MChart"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>QASKU URDU PARSER</title>
<!-- scripting code is deleted -->
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" method="get"  >

<div align="center" onKeyPress="return checkSubmit(event)">
<h4>QASKU URDU PARSER</h4><br>
<h5>Type sentence using Urdu/Arabic script only and then press the 'Parse' button below</h5><br>
<textarea cols="100" rows="5" style="text-align: right" name="mytextarea" id="message" >Type here</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript"> blurfocus("message"); </script>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Parse" >
</div>

</form>

<%
try
{
    if ( request.getParameter("mytextarea") == null)
    {
        out.println("<p align='center'>No Any Input Yet</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        <!-- database entries are deleted -->

        // inputting sentence from user and splitting into an array of strings

        String sent = request.getParameter("mytextarea");
        String[] input = sent.split(" ");


        //initialize chart and root rule
        MChart[] chart = new MChart[input.length+1];
        // only beginning instance is initiated and the rest will be initiated on 
           runtime // This also the NULL pointer creating statement
           chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed");

        out.println("<p><table align=center border='1' bgcolor='green' width='75%'><col width='25'><col width='25'><col width='25'><col width='25'><col width='25'>");
        out.println("<tr><th align=left>STATEID</th><th align=left>RULE</th><th align=left>DOT-POSITON</th><th align=left>BACK-POINTER</th><th align=left>OPERATION</th></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td align=left>"+chart[i].getStateID(i)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td align=left>"+chart[i].getRule(i)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td align=left>"+chart[i].getDotPosition(i)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td align=left>"+chart[i].getBackPointer(i)+"</td>");
        out.println("<td align=left>"+chart[i].getOperation(i)+"</td></tr>");
        out.println("</table></p>");


}
catch (Throwable any) 
{
    out.println("<p align=center>Java ERROR: "+any+"</p>");
    any.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? What is `i` in the jsp? Where is it assigned? My guess is it exceeds 99 at some point.

Comment: I am hanging with this from 2 days, so that's the reason I ask. Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Comment: `chart[i].getStateID(i)` Are you sure that shouldn't be `chart[0].getStateID(i)` ?

Comment: i is nothing, simply a variable which i am using for indexing.

Comment: actually, NULL pointer exception is appearing on this line :  chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed");

Answer (score 0):

looking at just the java I think I can see the problem

Space for 100 strings is reserved

```
private  String[] stateId = new String [100];
```

The FIRST and only the first is initialised as the s input

```
stateId[0]  =   s;
```

Any value other than 0 will give a null pointer exception

```
public String getStateID(int i)
{
    return stateId[i];
}
```

Comment: Of course the same is true for rule[0], dotPosition[0], backPointer[0] and operation[0] but you get the idea

Comment: Yeah, you'll get to the problems i mentioned but you're right. Its the same concept though: 
MChart[] chart = new MChart[input.length+1]; //reserve space for some number of MCharts. chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed"); //CALLS chart[0]'s method intialize, doesn't contruct it. As chart[0] hasn't been constructed yet you get this problem (there is no chart[0] yet so you can't call its methods. There should be a chart[0]=new MChart() somewhere before this

Comment: This is not a problem. You know normally we create arrays with different sizes and we are often not used these arrays fully. The problem is somewhere else Richtea. chart[0]=new MChart() is not needed because it is already done in MChart[] chart = new Mchart[....]

Comment: As an alternative: It would be more normal to do what you've done within in intialize in the objects constructor, so 'public void intialize(String s, String r, String dp, String bp, String o)' would become 'public MChart(String s, String r, String dp, String bp, String o)' and then when you created a new MChart you'd just chart[0]=new MChart("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed");

Comment: I get that an array doesn't have to be fully used, but you've not created even the first entry in the array, all the entries are null. Looking at what 'chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed");' does: chart[0] gets chart[0] (its null), call intialize on null (null pointer exception!)

Comment: p.s. see Petes answer, he's saying the same thing

Comment: I could not do this initialization in constructor, because for example I have 9 chart objects, the first one I want to  initialized  with this initialize() method and further will be initialized by resulting values of previous objects.

Comment: But you can't call initialize on an object that hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: Thats fine, as I said it just an alternative, but some constructor must always be called for an object, even if its the blank constructor MChart(). You have to remember that your constructor (silently) calls all the constructors below it, so your blank constructor calls the Object() constructor, without the object constructor its not an object

Comment: Calling `new MChart()` does 2 things (at least): It allocates the object in memory and it calls the constructor function. The object does not exist until you call its constructor and thus you can't call its methods.

Comment: trust me put chart[0] = new MChart(); on the line before chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed"); and your null pointer exception will go away (I think there are a few more further on, but one bridge at a time)

Answer (score 0):

`MChart[] chart = new MChart[input.length+1];`

This allocates an array of `null` MChart objects. You immediately reference `chart[0].intialize("0", "ROOT S", "0,0", "-1", "Seed");`

What you want to do first is `chart[0] = new MChart()` or something along those lines. Obviously you'll need to do this for every slot in the array.